# Showing multiline titles in Android notifications

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have gone through the following tutorials

1. https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/expanded.html
2. https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html

I want to show notifications with multiple line as shown in the layout below.[image: Prototype layout]

But I am not able to see the multiline text as shown in the image below. The first line is the title, while the second line is the body.

[image: Actual Notification Title]

Here is my code to build the notification builder.

```
// Helper function to create NotificationChannels and a builder for the channel id.
final NotificationCompat.Builder builder = makeNotificationBuilder();
        if (builder == null)
            return null;

        final RemoteViews collapsedView = new RemoteViews(context, R.layout.notification_template);
        builder.setContent(contentView);

        // Trying to set the text
        NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle style = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
        builder.setStyle(style);
        if (notification.getTitle() != null)
            builder.setContentTitle(notification.getTitle());
            style.setBigContentTitle(notification.getTitle());
        if (notification.getBody() != null)
            builder.setContentText(notification.getBody());
            style.bigText(notification.getBody());

        . . . . . Code to set the intent.. It works 


        if (expandedView != null)
            builder.setCustomBigContentView(expandedView);

        builder.setAutoCancel(true);

        return builder.build();
```

Layout file

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="false"
    android:background="@drawable/notification_material_bg">

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/notification_title"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:ellipsize="end"
      android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
      android:singleLine="false"
      android:maxLines="2"
      android:textAppearance="@style/NotificationTitle"
      tools:ignore="Deprecated"
      />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/notification_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
                android:textAppearance="@style/NotificationText"
                tools:ignore="Deprecated"
                />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you add notification_template layout file

Comment: @shobhan I have added the layout template.

Comment: any update for this?

Comment: I am afraid not.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set any orientation for `LinearLayout`.

Replace `android:orientation="false"` with
    `android:orientation="vertical"`

[image]

Comment: Does that prevent the multiline title to be displayed?

Comment: @Kartik no.I have edited my post by adding the output.